# Unable to resolve static field....when using HttpClientBuilder

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I was trying to create an httpClient instance with this line of code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Compiling is ok but when the code is executed, I got these errors

```
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5520 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0109
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5720 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0111
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultUserTokenHandler;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5758 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultUserTokenHandler;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x012f
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/NoConnectionReuseStrategy;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5538 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/NoConnectionReuseStrategy;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x01b4
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5520 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x01b8
I/dalvikvm(21590): Could not find method org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 15073: Lorg/apache/http/client/protocol/RequestDefaultHeaders;.<init> (Ljava/util/Collection;)V
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x01f0
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5721 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x02db
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x49b4 at 0x212 in Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;.build
I/dalvikvm(21590): Could not find method org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute.getLocalSocketAddress, referenced from method org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15468: Lorg/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute;.getLocalSocketAddress ()Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0020
D/dalvikvm(21590): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter;.INSTANCE
W/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6374 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter;
D/dalvikvm(21590): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
W/dalvikvm(21590): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchFieldError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/http/impl/io/DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory;
W/dalvikvm(21590): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchFieldError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory;
I/JPTFB   (21590): WebView Console: ERROR -
```

#

I have all of the libraries included:
httpclient-4.3.3.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I tried to use the desktop Java versions of the Apache HTTP libraries in an Android project. The solution for me was to simply resort to the Android build of the library (available at the [Google Code project site](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)). Make sure to remove the old imports afterwards and replace them by the versions from the library.