# ClassCastException: ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: android, retrofit, apache-commons-httpclient, httpclientandroidlib

I need to instantiate a [retrofit apache client](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/client/ApacheClient.htm)  with my custom `HttpClient`.

I run it in a project out of Android without any prloblem, but when I port it in my Android project I encountered problems about `Unable to resolve static field` ...after some research I found 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828678/1657028) that convinced me to try integrate  the [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) in my code.

The problem now consists in `ClassCastException: ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`
at the line:

```
    .setClient(new ApacheClient((HttpClient)UnsafeHttpsClient.createUnsafeClient())) // (new ApacheClient(UnsafeHttpsClient.createUnsafeClient())) // FR Qui usa Retrifit
```

```java
mSymtService = new SecuredRestBuilder()
    .setLoginEndpoint(TEST_URL + VideoSvcApi.TOKEN_PATH)
    .setClient(new ApacheClient((HttpClient)UnsafeHttpsClient.createUnsafeClient())) // (new ApacheClient(UnsafeHttpsClient.createUnsafeClient())) // FR Qui usa Retrifit
    .setEndpoint(TEST_URL).setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).build()
    .create(SymtMngmSrvcApi.class);
```

reported by LogCat:

`11-01 07:17:07.723: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
11-01 07:17:07.723: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at ![org.coursera.symtmngm.SymtMngmBaseActivity.signIn][1](SymtMngmBaseActivity.java:132)
11-01 07:17:07.723: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at org.coursera.symtmngm.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:75)`

This is the method that return my custom HttpClient:

```java
    public static HttpClient createUnsafeClient() {
    try {
        ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder builder = new ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                builder.build());
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

        return httpclient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

This is my class path: 
[image]

### Update: SOLVED

I solved by using 
[httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5) instead of httpclientandroidlib

Comment: "cannot be cast to" is correct. The Java language specification mandates that this happens. The problem is that your lib version is repackaged and therefore no longer compatible

Comment: thanks, your comment drive me to the solution: instead of httpclientandroidlib I've referenced httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar and this fixed the problem